# Continuous complex functions on a compact set

Tags: complex-analysis

From real analysis I know that every continuous real-valued function on a compacted set is bounded. I am just thinking will this also hold for complex-valued function? Or do I need to replace "continuous" with other thing like "holomorphic" to make it true?

Comment: Hint: $u+iv$ is continuous iff both $u,v$ are continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following fact from general topology:

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. If $f: X \to Y$ is continuous it maps compact sets to compact sets.

In particular, for $Y = \mathbb C$ a continuous map $f$ maps compact sets to compact sets.

Also, by Heine-Borel, a compact set in $\mathbb C$ is closed and bounded. Therefore the image of the compact set is bounded therefore $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Actually, I think the last paragraph can use a little bit of correction. Heine-Borel theorem states the inverse argument; that every closed and bounded set is compact.

Comment: @arsaKasra https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem